# Overloading >= operator

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I need to overload operator `>=`. If the condition is true, the operator returns `true`, otherwise `false`. If at least one of the objects is `null` – throw an exception (`ArgumentException`). I tried this. What's wrong?

```
public static bool operator false(Staff inputPerson)
{
    if ((inputPerson.salary) <= 15000)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if ((inputPerson.salary) is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("This person does not have a job");
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: You are not overloading >= in the above method.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Comparing to staff members like `staffA >= staffB` doesn't make any sense and it makes the code cryptic. `staffA.Salary >= staffB.Salary` is a lot cleaner.

Comment: @xxbbcc does indeed have a valid point.  When you are overloading an operator you do need to ask if your comparison makes sense.  Salary alone does not appear to be a good candidate for comparing two staff objects.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do something like `public static bool operator <= (Rational rational1, Rational rational2)`

When you overload this, you need to ensure that you overload all the related operators too. e.g. <, > <=, >= etc. as well as the equality operators and methods.

You need to pass in both of the objects to be compared, as the method is static, and not an instance method.

Comment: +1 for the comment about overloading all the operators.

Comment: Can you edit this question. I was on my phone and accidentally downvoted and it won't let me remove the downvote.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have edited it to +1. Got to be more careful on my phone lol.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static bool operator >=(Staff p1, Staff p2) {
    if (p1 is null || p2 is null) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("This person does not have a job");
    }
    return p1.salary >= p2.salary;
}
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: `>=` would return a `bool`.

Comment: Why would `>=` return a `Staff` object instead of a `bool`?

Comment: Oups. Copy and paste mistake. Fixed. Thanks!!